# Installing opencart on localhost

Tags: php, mysql, localhost, opencart

I took complete backup of opencart from my web server with database.Now I want to install it on the localhost so that I can make changes at the code, and can test it locally.So I copied the folder into the root directory of local server.The made a new database for it.Then edit the config.php file it looks like this.

```
    <?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://localhost/sillypunter/ocart/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://localhost/sillypunter/ocart/')
// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://localhost/sillypunter/ocart/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', 'sillypunter/ocart/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM',     'sillypunter/ocart/system/');
define('DIR_DATABASE',  'sillypunter/ocart/system/database/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', 'sillypunter/ocart/catalog/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', 'sillypunter/ocart/catalog/view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG',  'sillypunter/ocart/system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', 'sillypunter/ocart/image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', 'sillypunter/ocart/system/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', 'sillypunter/ocart/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', 'sillypunter/ocart/system/logs/');

// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysqli');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'sp_user');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'sp1234');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'sp_ocar');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'sp_');
?>
```

But on browser it is giving me server error 500.I'am using ubuntu 14.04,apache2, mysql and php. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: You must have to give absolute path in your `DIR` constant like `C:\wamp\www\yoursitefolder/catalog/`.

Comment: localhost apache recognize the relative path.It not need to be an absolute path. But I try this also ,same error.

Comment: Do one thing, Install fresh opencart in your system and then check its `config.php` file. Or may be check your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Can you show us what you see in your error_log? This will help to begin to narrow it down.

Comment: @LeonardChallis error_log file is not updating with the current error's.

Comment: May be this is due to `.htaccess` or `config.php` file or `root folder` permission. Give root folder permission to `755`

Comment: I already checked the file permission.

Answer (score 2):

define('DIR_APPLICATION', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'sillypunter/ocart/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM',     $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'sillypunter/ocart/system/');
define('DIR_DATABASE',  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'sillypunter/ocart/system/database/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'sillypunter/ocart/catalog/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'sillypunter/ocart/catalog/view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG',  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'sillypunter/ocart/system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'sillypunter/ocart/image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'sillypunter/ocart/system/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'sillypunter/ocart/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'sillypunter/ocart/system/logs/');

Comment: This din't work out.Same problem any other edit in any other file you can suggest.Will be of great help.